# SP2-0310: unable to open file .sql

Tags: java, oracle

I am calling batch file from my java program which in result execute some .sql files.
the batch script is below:

```
set part1= CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY REPORT AS '
set total=%part1%%4';
echo %total% > DIR_REPORT.sql
echo exit; >>DIR_REPORT.sql
sqlplus %1/%2@%3 @./DIR_REPORT.sql
sqlplus %1/%2@%3 @./PACKAGE_SCRIPTv2.sql
```

and my java code is :

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.println("Start Running the batch file");
Process p = run.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c", "start", "C:/Users/sony/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CodeReview/src/codereview/install.bat",i,j,m,l});
System.out.println("Completed");
```

it is giving error:

```
SP2-0310: unable to open file
```

The first file generated using the batch (DIR_REPORT) is being executed but my PACKAGE_SCRIPTv2.sql is not being executed but raises error, please help me what to do.

although when a run batch file mannualy from cmd everything works fine...

Comment: Do you have permissions to access the file?

Comment: Yes I have, but how can i Check that ?

Comment: If you're on windows right-click on the file then click properties.

Comment: I have all the permission, I verified...

Answer (score 0):

The first script is being created and executed in the current working directory, so it will always exist (assuming you have permission to create there). The second is expected to be in the current working directory as well. The question is, then, what is the current working directory?

It looks like you're expecting it to be `C:/Users/sony/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CodeReview/src/codereview/`, and if you run the `.bat` manually there it works OK (from what you've said); so when you call it from Java it must be somewhere else. That will either be whatever the working directory was when your JVM launched, or your home directory, I think - not quite sure.

You need to specify the correct directory, either hard-coded into the script, or passed as another parameter. You may then want to `cd` to that in your script so the `DIR_REPORT.sql` is created in the same, known, place; otherwise you can use it create the full path to `PACKAGE_SCRIPTv2.sql`.

Answer (score 0):

yeah the problem is path defined in statement contains all the files but while execution the script is going only till :

"C:/Users/sony/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CodeReview"

This is what was displayed in cmd, so I have placed the file into this directory and it started working...don't know the reason.

TIP: when you find such kind of issue please look at the error message properly as it will tell you where the script is looking when it got failed, so just place the file at that location and will work...

Enjoy \m/

Comment: Don't the reason... what, that it started working, or that it was looking in that directory in the first place? As I said in my answer, it looks like the working directory from when the JVM launched; maybe you have a shortcut to launch NetBeans that sets that working area, or you were in that directory when you launched the project. It might change depending on how you launch though, so it'll be safer to tell the script where to look, won't it?